# Pull date record is first in current status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the current record information and a history table.  Each time a record is updated a new record is created in the current table and the previous is moved to the history table.  I want to return the date when the current client, connection, status was first set.  The kicker is the connection could move out of and back into the current status so I can't just generically look for the first date in the history table that matches the client, connection, status from the ConnectionStatus table.  In the example below I would be looking to return the DateChanged from the second record in the history table - 1-19-2021.

ConnectionStatus

| Client | Connection | Status | DateChanged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1234 | 4 | 1-27-2021 |

ConnectionStatusHistory

| Client | Connection | Status | DateChanged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1234 | 4 | 1-24-2021 |
| ABCD | 1234 | 4 | 1-19-2021 |
| ABCD | 1234 | 3 | 1-16-2021 |
| ABCD | 1234 | 3 | 1-12-2021 |
| ABCD | 1234 | 4 | 1-8-2021 |

Comment: Hello Dale, My first attempt was a union query to and then utilized LEAD and OVER in the select section to compare the records.  This worked really well in giving the date difference for each record in the history table but couldn't identify the specific date in the select. I believe I need to loop through the history table in order to read each record and have it stop when the criteria on the next no longer matches.  Also it is possible that the current ConnectionStatus is the first it has been in that particular combination.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  One method is to get the most recent date associated with another status and then only choose rows bigger than that:

```
select csh.client, csh.connection, csh.status, min(csh.date)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when most_recent_status <> status then date end) over (partition by client, connection) as other_date
      from (select csh.*,
                   first_value(csh.status) over (partition by client, connection order by date desc) as most_recent_status
            from ConnectionStatusHistory csh 
           ) csh
     ) csh
where date > other_date or other_date is null
group by client, connection, status;
```

A more clever approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select client, connection, status, min(date)
from (select csh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client, connection order by date desc) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by client, connection, status order by date desc) as seqnum_s
      from ConnectionStatusHistory csh 
     ) csh
where seqnum = seqnum_s
group by client, connection, status;
```

This is more inscrutable.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see that `seqnum` enumerates all the rows starting from the most recent as 1.  Then `seqnum_s` enumerates the rows by status.  These values are equal only when the status is the most recent status.

Comment: Gordon, sorry it took me a while to get back.  The second solution works great. I ended up with a union for the ConnectionStatus and ConnectionStatusHistory tables in the from for the subquery.